# Test running before setup Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing, capybara, factory-bot

I am doing some integration testing using Capybara and I am encountering a problem when running tests. It seems the setup I have is not running before the tests, or at least the second test that is run. Here are the tests I have so far:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserSignupTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

    setup do
        FactoryGirl.create(:user_role)
    end

    test "user organic signup" do
        visit new_user_registration_path
        assert page.has_content?('Sign up for Connectedtrips')

        fill_in('Email', :with => "hugo@gmail.com")
        fill_in('First name', :with => "Hugo")
        fill_in('Last name', :with => "KH")
        choose("is_teacher_no")
        choose("owns_center_no")
        fill_in("Password", :with => "password")
        fill_in("Password confirmation", :with => "password")
        click_button("Sign up")

        assert page.has_content?("Your registration is complete - thanks for joining!")
    end

    test "teacher organic signup" do
        visit new_user_registration_path
        assert page.has_content?('Sign up for Connectedtrips')
        fill_in('Email', :with => "another@gmail.com")
        fill_in('First name', :with => "Another")
        fill_in('Last name', :with => "")
        choose("is_teacher_yes")
        choose("owns_center_no")
        fill_in("Password", :with => "password")
        fill_in("Password confirmation", :with => "password")
        click_button("Sign up")

        assert page.has_content?("Your registration is complete - thanks for joining!")
    end
end
```

And here is the code in my test helper. I tried to set it up as best I could, I'm not sure if I need database cleaner as I am using Datamapper instead of Active Record, for the record I don't know if this makes a difference.

ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', **FILE**)
require 'rails/test_help'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'database_cleaner'

```
module ActionController
  class IntegrationTest
    include Capybara::DSL
    DataMapper.auto_migrate!

    def teardown
      DatabaseCleaner.clean 
      Capybara.reset_sessions!
      Capybara.use_default_driver
      destroy_all
    end

    def destroy_all
        # destroying all my tables here 
      end

  end
end
```

This is the error I am receiving:

```
UserSignupTest
     PASS test_teacher_organic_signup (0:00:00.929)
    ERROR test_user_organic_signup (0:00:00.998)
          ERROR:  insert or update on table "users" violates foreign key constraint "users_role_fk"
          DETAIL:  Key (role_id)=(1) is not present in table "roles".
```

I am not quite sure how to solve this and I would appreciate some help thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this and thought I'd just put up my solution. What I did was in the teardown where I was destroying all my tables I left out the Role table from being destroyed. The on the setup I did:

```
Role.first(:name => "User") || FactoryGirl.create(:user_role)
```

This may be overkill. Anyway problem solved I guess.